# How to pull code (after wrongly running the push and delete commands)

Tags: xcode, git, github

I am new to Git. I wrongly uploaded my code into GitHub repository with push command using Xcode source control. Then I asked a question that how can I delete the content of the master, because I thought that deleting files is enough to have a fresh start. (NB: I cannot delete the repository and create a new one) so I deleted every single file in repository with push command and the repository is empty now.  When I try to pull my local working copy this time, my local working copy got deleted.

Does anyone know how can I pull my code?

Comment: "Does any one know how can I pull my code" What code? You deleted it.

Comment: I have an extra copy of my code. @matt

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to go about fixing this problem.

1. Rewrite your history and push the rewrite to master (not recommended, because it will screw up everyone else's history as well, but has the benefit if making it appear that you never made a mistake)
2. Make a new commit reverting your changes and push this new commit.  This keeps your old code in the repository but removes it from subsequent versions.  It also has the added benefit of not screwing up everyone else's history.

To accomplish #1, simply run `git log` and find the commit ID number, then run `git reset NUMBER` to revert your tree to the working state.  Then push your changes with `git push RemoteName BranchName --force`

As I mentioned, I *strongly* recommend against doing that unless you have some major privacy concerns over your mistake.  A much better way to handle the problem is to run `git revert CommitID` to create a new commit that "undoes" your previous mistake.  Check out [this Atlassian blurb](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert/) for a bit on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  I think you first solution is fine. since, I am the only person who push codes, others have not participated yet. Just a quick question. Then when I revert it, should I push changes or pull it ?

Comment: Push!  and make sure to use the --force option or the repository will think you are "behind" and not let you push.

Comment: I follow your steps from the first solution. I back to my initial commit. How can I back to the time when there was not any commit. My first commit is done by a push. I want to redo it by a pull.

Comment: I am unsure of what you are asking. If you have done anything at all in a git repo, you shouldn't have to pull anything down. Use git log to find the commit you want to reset to, then use git reset to turn back the clock.

Comment: I want to back to the time that the repo is made (no commit). I could not find the number for that time. I found the number for the first commit and I did run the reset and lastly pushed it as you said,so the repository's time returned to initial commit. Is it possible to back one step before initial commit?

Comment: Delete the repo...  (.git folder)

Comment: btw, sorry if I am too new to git. I just started to learn it for few hours. Thanks alot for your support til now.

Comment: No problem! I'm sorry I didn't get you immediately. Check this video out, it's my fav for overview and goes into how some of the commands I mentioned work. http://youtu.be/1ffBJ4sVUb4